# Text extraction from multiple websites

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib2
import urllib
list_open = open("weblist.txt")
read_list = list_open.read()
line_in_list = read_list.split("\n")
for url in line_in_list:
        Beautiful = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        beautiful
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(beautiful)
        for news in soup:
                 print soup.getText()
```

The following code helps me to extract text from multiple websites (weblist.txt)

but when my weblist contains any link or website which don't open with this code it stops immediately and not check further links. Suppose if I have 10 links and second one is not open or is not able to parse it gives error and stops in that link without checking further links.I want that it should check each link from weblist (start to end ) and extract text from all those links which are genuine or able to parse.

Comment: Maybe good to read: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: check status code before reading response(.read()),
ie. instead of doing this, 
Beautiful = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
simplify the expression, and handle exception,
try:
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    if resp.getcoode()==200:
        Beautiful = resp.read()
except Exception as e:
    # an error handling the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a try except statement like this:

```
for url in line_in_list:
    try:
        Beautiful = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        beautiful
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(beautiful)
        for news in soup:
             print soup.getText()
    except Exception as e:
        #Error handling
        print(e)
```

Comment: Thanks.This is actually, i want. Can u please further help me to move this text from python editor to file as i have do but not work                                                        file = open('test.txt','w')                                                                                         for url in line_in_list:
    try:
        Beautiful = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        beautiful
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(beautiful)
        for news in soup:
             print soup.getText()                                             
         file.write(soup.getText())

Comment: @yalikhan you probably forgot to close the file. At the end just add  `file.close()`